# How to install memcache (to ease mysql load) in php

Tags: memcache

I want to install memcache on my dedicated server, how do I do that using SSH?

OS: CENTOS 6.2 x86_64, PHP ver. 5.2.17, APC already installed.

Answer (score 3):

Just type

```
     yum install memcached.x86_64 php-pecl-memcache.x86_64
```

And you are done. More spoon feeding tutorial @ http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-memcached-under-rhel-fedora-centos/

Answer (score 2):

You should start by reading the [documentation](http://memcached.org/) and come back here to ask specific questions if you run into trouble.